# updating button images in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

i have some code that updates the images of a button, however, when i attempt to run the code i consistently get an error:

'fatal error: Array index out of range'

this code i am trying to run is below:

```
    func updateButtonImages() {
    let buttons = total.map { buttonList[$0] }
    **buttons[0].setImage(UIImage(named: "p2"), forState: .Normal)**



    var time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0)
    for (priorButton, currentButton) in zip(buttons[0..<buttons.count - 1], buttons[1..<buttons.count]) {
        time = dispatch_time(time, Int64(speed * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            priorButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "p2"), forState: .Normal)
            currentButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "p1"), forState: .Normal)
        }
    }

    time = dispatch_time(time, Int64(speed * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        buttons.last?.setImage(UIImage(named: "p1"), forState: .Normal)
        //replayButton.enabled = true
        self.buttonList.forEach { $0.enabled = true }
    }
}
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this issue?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error : **fatal error: Array index out of range** contains and answer as well.

You try to work with item that is not in range of this array.

Example:

```
var items = [1, 2]

items[2] // error only items are available at indexes 0 and 1
```

So in you're code check **buttonList** array.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i have updated the code above and surrounded the line in double asterisks, which causes the error in xcode, but I fully understand the answer you have provided, i am still unsure if it is to do with the **buttonList** array, or  **buttons**

Comment: buttons is empty or nil